# NSNumber from a NSDictionary return nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I am working on a Watch App, and am trying to pass a NSNumber to the next controller.

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];
    NSNumber* test = (NSNumber*) [(NSDictionary*) context objectForKey:@"collId"];
}
```

However, the variable test is always 'nil', while the context dictionary seems to contain the value '(long)0' which is the value assigned.

[image]

In this case added as an NSNumber* in the preceding controller:

```
- (id) contextForSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)segueIdentifier inTable:(WKInterfaceTable *)table rowIndex:(NSInteger)rowIndex {
    if ([segueIdentifier isEqualToString:@"segueList"]) {
        DWCollRow* theRow = [table rowControllerAtIndex:rowIndex];

        NSDictionary *userInfo = @{theRow.colId:@"collId"};
        return userInfo;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Aren't you inverting key and object in your `NSDictionary`? Key seems to be @0, and value seems to be `collId`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = @{theRow.colId:@"collId"}; //for this
@"Key" : @"Value"// you wrote this opposite
```

It should be

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = @{@"collId":theRow.colId};
```